# Typescript JSON Schema Validation with API Testing

Tags: json, typescript

So im seeing some conflicting results on whether this is possible or not. From searching I've found threads on here stating that schema validation is NOT possible on runtime with Typescript.

However i've also read recently that you can do this via the "Type Assertions" using Typescript. Something similar to this:

```
interface User {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  email: string
}
```

and then doing something like this (doing API testing for example)

```
const response = await fetch("someUrlthatReturnsaUser")
const json = response.text()
const user = JSON.parse(json) as User
```

Presumably this won't give you any information within the IDE or anything, BUT it should presumably fail? If it doesn't match the schema.

Is this possible or even the right way to do this? This seems similar to deserialization in C# or something similar.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. How to validate your schema? There are different tools that can validate schemas. Yes, it's possible but you have to try something. Just casting an object which is typed as `any` does not validate anything. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-json-schema

Comment: @RuanMendes I guess what im asking is if "User" when it's being casted is a reliable way to catch errors in JSON schema validation if the response doesn't deserialize correctly into the interface defined in the example.

Comment: And I did already say that it's not. Casting does not do actual data validation, only type validation. Since `JSON.parse(json)` returns `any`, casting is not even validating the type. You are telling the compiler that you know what you are doing.

Comment: @RuanMendes Won't I get an error at runtime if it doesn't correctly correlate to the interface? Or I guess Typescript doesn't really work during run-time so I guess it doesn't exactly matter maybe?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76341718/227299) explaining how to safely convert from JSON to a TS interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do type checking at runtime with JS but it takes some work since TypeScript is erased from the compiled code. It requires two steps:

##### Generate a [JSON Schema from your User interface](https://github.com/vega/ts-json-schema-generator)

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "firstName",
    "lastName",
    "email"
  ]
}
```

##### Use a [type-safe schema validator](https://ajv.js.org/guide/typescript.html#type-safe-parsers-and-serializers) to validate your data

```
const data = parse(json) // User | undefined
if (data === undefined) {
    console.log(parse.message) // error message from the last parse call
    console.log(parse.position) // error position in string
  } else {
    // data is User here
    console.log(user.firstName)
  }
}
```

There are multiple tools to do each of these steps. What I have linked to are just examples. You can play around with https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Comment: Thanks, seems like it's possible but also a pretty heavy lift as well.

Comment: Yes, I don't do any of this from most of my remote calls because I rely on the backend fulfilling its promise, that is, there's some validation before the backend sends the JSON to the client and the TS definitions (DTOs) are created by the backend and shared with the client beforehand.